# Applying Different colours to bars in sencha touch bar charts

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

```
renderer: function(sprite, record, attr, index, store) {
                        var colors =    ['#9CC5C9','#D5544F','#D5544F','#5288DB'];

                        return Ext.apply(attr, {
                            fill: colors[index % colors.length]
                        });
                    },
```

I am working with sencha touch 2.2.1 Charts. I need to colour the bars using different colours. when i googled i found the above piece of code as solution suggested by many.

Unfortunately this is not working for me..! :( ;(

i tried the theme concept and some other solutions too. but it looks like too complex.

So plz plz help me on this..! :(

Comment: And what is not working ? The code looks OK. Do you get any errors ?

Comment: There is no errors, to check whether this function is executing, i tried to print something in console. it seems that part of code is not executing. i dont know why ! :(

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
renderer: function (sprite, config, rendererData, index) {
    var colors =    ['#9CC5C9','#D5544F','#D5544F','#5288DB'];
    return { strokeStyle: colors[index % colors.length] };        
}
```